# Probability without replacement

Tags: probability, combinations

A box contains 14 balls numbered 1 through 14. If 3 balls are selected one at a time from the box, without replacement, what is the probability that the largest number selected will be 10? Note this is different from being told that all selected balls are less than or equal to a value. You are actually given the value of one of the selected balls.

The answer in decimal is 0.099 but I have no idea how to get it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  it is easy to compute the probability that the max, $M$,  will be less than or equal to a particular value.  So then just compute $P(M≤10)-P(M≤9)$.

Comment: But then am I not accounting for the balls numbered 11-14?

Comment: What do you mean?  They show up in the probabilities.  The probability that the first ball is $≤10$ is $\frac {10}{14}$.  That $14$ in the denominator has all the information you need.

Comment: From what I understood I should have : 
(10/14) - (9/13) - (8/12) = - ( 176/273)

Comment: Not following your notation.  $P(M≤10)=\frac {10}{14} \times \frac 9{13} \times \frac 8{12}=\frac {30}{91}$

Comment: ok, thank you. I was adding them instead of multiplying them. So from here what is the next step?

Comment: Now do the same to compute $P(M≤9)$.  Can you see why the answer you want is the difference, $P(M≤10)-P(M≤9)$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

In other words, you **must** choose the ball labeled $10$. This is the max, and since it is the max, all other balls you choose must be lower than $10$. Clearly, there are $9$ such balls: the ones labeled $1$ through $9$. Since the order doesn't matter, we can imagine that these nine are green, the $10$ is white, and the rest are blue. So, what do we need to count in order to guarantee that we get the $10$ and two lower valued balls?

Comment: so the white ball would be ( 10!/ (1!9!), the blue 14!/(4!9!) and the green 9!/(2!7!). Would it be 1-blue balls + white + green?

Comment: There's only **one** white ball. So counting the number of ways to get that one ball is $\binom{1}{1} = 1$. $\binom{10}{1}$ basically counts how many ways you can make groups of 1 out of a set of 10, which doesn't make sense to use in this problem. Neither does the second number you gave, which appears to be a typo. The green number makes sense. It's counting the number of ways to get two labeled green balls from the set of 9. But then "1-blue balls+white+green" doesn't make sense. It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: @Charlotte You want the probability that the *three* balls selected from *fourteen* will be the 10 and *two* from the *nine* numbers less than 10.